# Removing from array field items that match the ones in a list

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aws-documentdb

Suppose I have this document structure:

```
{
     "_id": <ObjectId goes here>,
     "postBody": "test",
     "photos": [
          {"url": "url1.com", "status": 0},
          {"url": "url2.com", "status": 0},
          {"url": "url3.com", "status": 0},
          {"url": "url4.com", "status": 0}
     ]
}
```

And I have this list of urls that I want to delete

```
toDelete = ["url2.com", "url3.com"]
```

How do I do this in a mongo query?

Here is what I've tried so far

```
db.Post.update_one(
     {"_id": <ObjectId goes here>},
     {
          "$pull": {
               "photos": {
                    "url": {
                         "$in": toDelete
                    }
               }
          }
     }
)
```

But somehow it is not working. How should I do this?

After the update the document should already look like this

```
{
     "_id": <ObjectId goes here>,
     "postBody": "test",
     "photos": [
          {"url": "url1.com", "status": 0},
          {"url": "url4.com", "status": 0}
     ]
}
```

I need help.

Update: I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/chalice/app.py", line 1104, in _get_view_function_response
    response = view_function(**function_args)
  File "/var/task/chalicelib/Post/controllers/post_controller.py", line 62, in edit_post
    raise e
  File "/var/task/chalicelib/Post/controllers/post_controller.py", line 59, in edit_post
    result = POSTSERVICE.edit_post(post_data)
  File "/var/task/chalicelib/Post/services/post_service.py", line 362, in edit_post
    raise e
  File "/var/task/chalicelib/Post/services/post_service.py", line 315, in edit_post
    "$in": toDelete
  File "/var/task/pymongo/collection.py", line 1003, in update_one
    session=session),
  File "/var/task/pymongo/collection.py", line 856, in _update_retryable
    _update, session)
  File "/var/task/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1492, in _retryable_write
    return self._retry_with_session(retryable, func, s, None)
  File "/var/task/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1385, in _retry_with_session
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/var/task/pymongo/collection.py", line 852, in _update
    retryable_write=retryable_write)
  File "/var/task/pymongo/collection.py", line 767, in _update
    common.validate_boolean("upsert", upsert)
  File "/var/task/pymongo/common.py", line 159, in validate_boolean
    raise TypeError("%s must be True or False" % (option,))
TypeError: upsert must be True or False
```

Comment: It should work, I've tested it just to make sure it's working. `<ObjectId goes here>` is this of type `ObjectId()` or string ? just do `.find()` to check if filter is working or not, if it's string convert to `ObjectId()`..

Comment: @whoami im getting an error. I updated my post

Comment: I tried this, I worked!

db.getCollection('t1').update({
     "_id": ObjectId("5eb548d0d636f32d234ac2c0") },
     {
          "$pull": {
               "photos": {
                    "url": {
                         "$in": ['url2.com']
                    }
               }
          }
     
    })

Comment: Yes, it even worked for me also. Could you provide rest of the relevant code?